# Query regarding PP complexity class vs NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Considering the complexity classes $NP$, $co-NP$ and $PP$:

1. $NP$ and $co-NP$ are both contained in $PP$.
2. For any Language *$L$* suppose we have the mechanism that: If the oracle of $co-NP$ implies $No$ on a modified version of $L$ (lets call it $L'$), then that we can be certain that for every run of $PP$ on $L$ would return $No$.

Does that imply something about the complexity of $PP$/$coPP$ (as $PP$ and $coPP$ are same) vs. $coNP$?

Wouldn't that mean $PP \subseteq coNP$ ?

Comment: Yes. Thus, I asked just for the partial condition, i.e. if Unsat(L') = true then  MajSAT(L) = false. If its SAT(L'), we can't say anything.

Comment: @rus9384 In fact, NP and coNP are both contained in PP. You can construct a polytime machine that on a formula on $n$ variables accepts with probability $1/2 + (S-1/2)/2^n$, where $S$ is the number of satisfying assignments.

Comment: @J.Doe I have no idea what you mean in (2). Can you try to rephrase?

Comment: Ok, roughly speaking given a language (L), and the query is does (L) belong to PP (Yes, if the answer MajSAT is true, else false). Now, if we could transform (L) into another Language (L') such that: "If L' is unsatisfiable, then we are certain that MajSAT is false."  (only the partial condition, as if L' is satisfiable, MajSAT can be either true or false). Does this condition say/add anything additional about complexity of co-NP vs PP?

Comment: @rus9384 That's the idea. An unsatisfiable formula is accepted with probability less than 1/2, while a satisfiable formula is accepted with probability more than 1/2. I had a typo - it should have been $1/2 + (S-1/2)/2^{n+1}$.

Comment: @J.Doe Unfortunately I still don't understand. For example, a language cannot be "unsatisfiable", and a language is in PP given that there is a probabilistic polytime Turing machine which accepts inputs in the languages with probability more than half, and accepts inputs not in the language with probability less than half.

Comment: apologies for the confusion. We are considering the MajSAT problem which is in PP (not any generic language). So, we convert the given MajSAT(L) problem into another problem L' with query: Is SAT(L') satisfiable? and the rest of the condition follows. i.e. if SAT(L') is false, then we are certain that  MajSAT(L) is false. So every run of PP would return a probability less than or equal to 1/2 on MajSAT(L).

Comment: @J.Doe, deciding half of MAJSAT instances isn't the same as decide them all. That applies everywhere: e. g. an algorithm that solves "YES" instances of NP-complete problem in polynomial time doesn't imply P = NP.

Comment: A polytime reduction from MAJSAT to SAT would show that P=PP. Is this your question?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, he means that UNSAT implies not MAJSAT. Since UNSAT can be answered using coNP machine, he asks about any conseuences (I believe none of such exist).

Answer (score 0):

No, this implies nothing. Suppose the coNP problem is TAUTOLOGY.  Here's a mechanism: given any formula $\varphi$, return a new formula $\varphi'$, where $\varphi' = \text{True}$.  Then the oracle will always return Yes, so the statement "If the oracle returns No then ..." will be vacuously true.  Yet the existence of my mechanism clearly proves nothing interesting (anything we could have proven by considering the consequences of my mechanism, we could have just as easily proven without it).